# Batch Monitoring graphical representation in JSF/ICEFaces

Tags: java, jsf-2, icefaces-3

I have a question related to display of batch monitoring in graphical way(blocks) with actions on click of blocks. Is it possible to achieve with applicatioin which is limited with front end tech as(JSF , ICEFaces).?

Is it possible to integrate any open source technology with above front end tech to achieve this requirement.?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Effectively, the answers to your questions are: "Yes", "No" . The no because you state **ANY** opensource technology (you might be able to integrate 'any', but the efforts might be really really high)

Comment: thanks for you info. Can u pls describe more on "Yes" part.